# snscrape twitter using Python

Tags: python, pandas, twitter, syntax-error, scrape

I just got an information that sncrape python still error, I tried to solve it by add top = True in line twi***scraper but it still error.
Here is my codes:

```
pd.options.display.max_colwidth = 500
query = "(music) lang:en  since:2023-01-01 until:2023-02-02" 
tweets = []
limit = 10
get_ipython().run_line_magic('time', '')
try:
    print("start scraping")
    for tweet in sntwitter.TwitterSearchScraper(query=query, top = True).get_items():
        if len(tweets) == limit :
            break
        else:
            tweets.append([tweet.date, tweet.user.username, tweet.content])
    df = pd.DataFrame(tweets, columns=['datetime', 'username', 'content'])
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

print("Finished")
print("-------")
```

Can somebody solved the error?

```
Error retrieving https://api.twitter.com/2/search/adaptive.json?include_profile_interstitial_type=1&include_blocking=1&include_blocked_by=1&include_followed_by=1&include_want_retweets=1&include_mute_edge=1&include_can_dm=1&include_can_media_tag=1&skip_status=1&cards_platform=Web-12&include_cards=1&include_ext_alt_text=true&include_quote_count=true&include_reply_count=1&tweet_mode=extended&include_entities=true&include_user_entities=true&include_ext_media_color=true&include_ext_media_availability=true&send_error_codes=true&simple_quoted_tweets=true&q=%28Gempa%29+lang%3Aid++since%3A2023-01-01+until%3A2023-02-02&count=100&query_source=spelling_expansion_revert_click&pc=1&spelling_corrections=1&ext=mediaStats%2ChighlightedLabel: non-200 status code
4 requests to https://api.twitter.com/2/search/adaptive.json?include_profile_interstitial_type=1&include_blocking=1&include_blocked_by=1&include_followed_by=1&include_want_retweets=1&include_mute_edge=1&include_can_dm=1&include_can_media_tag=1&skip_status=1&cards_platform=Web-12&include_cards=1&include_ext_alt_text=true&include_quote_count=true&include_reply_count=1&tweet_mode=extended&include_entities=true&include_user_entities=true&include_ext_media_color=true&include_ext_media_availability=true&send_error_codes=true&simple_quoted_tweets=true&q=%28Gempa%29+lang%3Aid++since%3A2023-01-01+until%3A2023-02-02&count=100&query_source=spelling_expansion_revert_click&pc=1&spelling_corrections=1&ext=mediaStats%2ChighlightedLabel failed, giving up.
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your code is correct (although your code has some warnings such as using `mode = snscrape.modules.twitter.TwitterSearchScraperMode.TOP` instead of `top = True` and using `rawContent` instead of `content`. But I had the same error. It happened to me when I used an Iranian ISP (Twitter is banned in Iran by the government). I figured out it related to your network and your ISP. I used VPN (also you can run your code on a server with access to free internet) and it will get fixed.

Answer (score 0):

To scrape top tweets do the following (since top=True is deprecated):

```
import snscrape.modules.twitter as sntwitter
```

and then

```
mode_param = sntwitter.TwitterSearchScraperMode.TOP
(sntwitter.TwitterSearchScraper(search_query, mode = mode_param)
```

Comment: could you write complete code? I'm still confuse about your idea to solve it.

Comment: @JokoAdeNursiyono 
search_query is your query. Example: 
search_query = "Bitcoin since:2023-03-23 until:2023-03-24 lang:en"
rest stays the same. there are plenty guides on the internet as to how to use snscrape with Python